# Spring webflow start flow and event from a external link (p.e. confirmation email)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

App send a confirmation email when an user register a new account. That email contain a link which must start a specific eventId for a flow which got several events. Link redirect properly to flow but I don't get this flow start on confirmation eventId, always it starts on first eventId called login.

url: *....aio/spring/login?_eventId=confirmation&code=cmFmYWVscnVpenRhYmFyZXNAZ21haWwuY29t*

I have read possible solutions using externalRedirect and others commands written on flow rules but I don't need that way.

**Login flow**

```
    <view-state id="login" view="login.xhtml">
    <transition on="entry" to="connect"/>
    <transition on="recoveryPass" to="recovery" />
</view-state>

<action-state id="connect">
    <evaluate expression="login.connect()" />
    <transition on="yes" to="finish" />
    <transition on="no" to="login" />
</action-state>

<view-state id="recovery" view="recovery.xhtml" model="loginFields">
    <transition on="return" to="login" />
    <transition on="sendPass" to="recoveryPass" />
</view-state>

<action-state id="recoveryPass">
    <evaluate expression="login.recoveryPass()" />
    <transition on="yes" to="login" />
    <transition on="error" to="error" />
</action-state>

<action-state id="confirmation">
    <on-entry>
        <set name="confirmationCode" value="requestParameters.code" type="string" />
    </on-entry>

    <evaluate expression="login.confirmation(confirmationCode)" />
    <transition on="yes" to="confirmationOk" />
    <transition on="no" to="noUserFound" />
    <transition on="error" to="error" />
</action-state>

<view-state id="confirmationOk" view="confirmation.xhtml">
  <!--<set name="viewScope.code" value="found" />  -->  
</view-state>

<view-state id="noUserFound" view="confirmation.xhtml">
    <!--<set name="viewScope.code" value="notFound" />-->  
</view-state>

<end-state id="finish" />

<subflow-state id="error" subflow="error">

</subflow-state>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

eventId is not same as state id - eventId is required for transitioning in a current state(action/view) of an ongoing flow and not for launching a new flow. The reason why you are landing on login could be that login-flow xml might be mapped to /login mapping and view-state with id login is the start state(by default first state in flow definition file will be start state) of login flow. You need to have a decision state as on start state to redirect to a state based on some conditional parameter whether you need to go to login state or confirmation state.

**EDIT:**

For example, if code parameter is present only when request is from email, then your flow definition could be like:

```
    <flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd">

    <input name="code" type="java.lang.String">

    <decision-state id="checkFlowStart">
        <if test="code == null" then="login" else="confirmation"/>
    </decision-state>

    <view-state id="login" view="login.xhtml">
        <transition on="entry" to="connect"/>
        <transition on="recoveryPass" to="recovery" />
    </view-state>
    ....
```

Comment: Could you explain what it's a stateId? Your idea looks good but what happens if I wish to reuse flow for several cases like 'confirmation'? That's mean I should write one 'decision-state' for each case?I think this behaviour could be a little tedious, isn't?

So, is it impossible to start a flow on a specific view/decision/action-state...overwritten the real sequence? I mean using external links as well using internal words as 'flowRedirect' and so on. Thanks!

Comment: @Rafael Ruiz Tabares state id am referencing to are identifiers of various states like desiscion-state, action-state, view-state.
*"is it impossible to start a flow on a specific view/decision/action-state"* - You can always specify start-state  as <flow ... start-state= "yourStartState">. If this is not specified, the first state that is defined in the flow will become the start state by default. This is what i mentioned above.

Comment: If I understand correctly - you have multiple scenarios with parameters like code for 'confirmation' etc.,- add one generic parameter identifying from where the flow is being invoked. Move the decision making logic to action-state and return appropriate eventId from that action state for transitioning to proper state.

Comment: Ajam,I was wrong, I thought your stateId definition was corresponded with eventId. So, what is eventId?

Comment: on attribute value of transition is evenId. In your code above: entry, recoveryPass, yes, no are eventIds to mention.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered make a particular state (implementation in that state) as a different flow. When using in the main flow it can be used as sub-flow and whereas it gives you a freedom to be launched as a separate flow as well.
The parameter from the main flow can be passed as inputs to the sub-flow. Below is an example I am trying to explain myself

```
Main Flow
<view-state></view-state>
<action-state></action-state>
<!-- This is the re-usable flow which can be used within this flow and can be
launched independently -->
<sub-flow>
  <input/>
</sub-flow>

Another spring flow - can be plugged in from another flow or used independently
<input/>
<action-state></action-state>
<end-state></end-state>
```